# sqoop job export data into mysql,stuck at map 100% with status running

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop, oozie, impala

So I was trying to export data from impala into mysql with sqoop,which is scheduled by oozie job.But when the first sqoop action start,it stuck at map 100% and reduce 0%.and all other action stuffed.

And what strange is that before I kill this oozie job,there is no data in mysql,but after I kill it,data appears in the mysql table(only the table concerned with the first stuck sqoop action).

Here is my export script:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf6Vx.png)
And my oozie job actions show below:
[the first running is the one stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHKQo.png)

And there is no error logs exist.

Comment: sorry about the picture,this is my first time to ask question here,and it seems that I am not able to edit it again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check logs from resource manager, you will find the possible error there.
You can see the logs from resource manager web UI.
The possible errors can be of datatype, datatype field width, format (in case of date or timestamped values).

Comment: yeah,I read the resource manager log,and find no error.But I do find that there writes log like this: appattempt_1490240402690_0020_000001 State change from SUBMITTED to SCHEDULED.  
     Which means the map-reduce job is stuck at SCHEDULED status. I wonder if my Physical machine is too poor. The cluster on one machine with 4 cores and 16G RAM,is that enough to run hadoop,yarn,hive,impala,sqoop all? Or maybe I have to adjust some configuration.